# STM8A CAN Filtering in Standard Peripheral Library

Tags: filter, can-bus, stm8

I am working with the STM8AF5286UDY and am trying to set up a CAN interface.
For programming, I use the standard peripheral library. At the moment, my CAN interface works fine. The only thing, which does not work, is filtering.

I use extended IDs and want to get all IDs from 0x18FEC100 to 0x18FEC999.
My code looks as follows:

```
/* CAN filter init */

 CAN_FilterNumber = CAN_FilterNumber_0;

 CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;

 CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask;

 CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_32Bit;

 CAN_FilterID1=0x18FEC101;

 CAN_FilterID2=0;

 CAN_FilterID3=0;

 CAN_FilterID4=0;

 CAN_FilterIDMask1=0x1FFFF000;

 CAN_FilterIDMask2=0;

 CAN_FilterIDMask3=0;

 CAN_FilterIDMask4=0;  

 CAN_FilterInit(CAN_FilterNumber, CAN_FilterActivation, CAN_FilterMode, 
         CAN_FilterScale,CAN_FilterID1, CAN_FilterID2, CAN_FilterID3,
         CAN_FilterID4,CAN_FilterIDMask1, CAN_FilterIDMask2, 
         CAN_FilterIDMask3, CAN_FilterIDMask4);
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

**EDIT:** In my initial code, I forgot to include IDE and RTR at addressing. Also, in the library, each address and mask is an 8-bit value. Therefore, I have changed my code to the following:

```
/* CAN filter init */
  CAN_FilterNumber = CAN_FilterNumber_2;
  CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask; 
  CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_32Bit; 
  CAN_FilterID1=0xc7;  
  CAN_FilterID2=0xed;
  CAN_FilterID3=0x02;
  CAN_FilterID4=0x02;
  CAN_FilterIDMask1=0xFF; 
  CAN_FilterIDMask2=0xE7; 
  CAN_FilterIDMask3=0xE0;
  CAN_FilterIDMask4=0x00; 
  CAN_FilterInit(CAN_FilterNumber, CAN_FilterActivation, CAN_FilterMode, 
                 CAN_FilterScale,CAN_FilterID1, CAN_FilterID2, CAN_FilterID3,
                 CAN_FilterID4,CAN_FilterIDMask1, CAN_FilterIDMask2, 
                 CAN_FilterIDMask3, CAN_FilterIDMask4);
```

This filter works for the first 16-bit, so at using 0x18FEC101 it filters the 0x18FE. Somehow, it does not work for the other 16-bit.

In the library, the following code is used for writing the addresses and masks in the filter bank at 32-bit:

```
else if (CAN_FilterScale == CAN_FilterScale_32Bit)
    {
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR01 = CAN_FilterID1;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR02 = CAN_FilterID2;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR03 = CAN_FilterID3;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR04 = CAN_FilterID4;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR05 = CAN_FilterIDMask1;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR06 = CAN_FilterIDMask2;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR07 = CAN_FilterIDMask3;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR08 = CAN_FilterIDMask4;
    }
```

Are there any ideas, what my mistake might be? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mask filtering works bitwise. So you can't create a filter to accept values between 0x18FEC100 - 0x18FEC999. You need to think binary.

In the filter mask registers, 1 means "must match" and 0 means "don't care".

ID = 0x18FEC101 and Mask = 0x1FFFF000 means that it will accept values between 0x18FEC000 - 0x18FECFFF as the filter won't care the least significant 12 bits.

**However**, the process is further complicated by the bit arrangement of the hardware registers. Be aware that RTR & IDE bits are also included in the filter registers. I don't know if the standard peripheral library handles this but probably not. You probably need to manually arrange the bits to determine the correct register values. In the reference manual (*RM0016*), refer to *Figure 148*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I totally forgot about the RTR & IDE bits.  
I changed my code and it works at least better than before. I can filter the first 16 bit of the addresses, so up to 0x18FE, but somehow my messages can't pass, if I add the next 4 bit, so the "C" to the filter...

Do you have any idea, any that might happen?

Comment: The current code looks like this (although posting it might be useless without the reference manual):   

  CAN_FilterNumber = CAN_FilterNumber_2;

  CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;

  CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask; 

  CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_32Bit; 

  CAN_FilterID1=0xc7;  

  CAN_FilterID2=0xed;

  CAN_FilterID3=0x02;

  CAN_FilterID4=0x02;

  CAN_FilterIDMask1=0xFF; 

  CAN_FilterIDMask2=0xE7; 

  CAN_FilterIDMask3=0xE0; 

  CAN_FilterIDMask4=0x00;

Comment: I guess library variables don't match with the hardware register names. In 32 bit mode, you can have only 1 ID and 1 mask for each filter, and these are 32 bit variables. Populate only `CAN_FilterID1` & `CAN_FilterIDMask1` with 32 bit variables, but also consider the positions of RTR & IDE bits. Also, check library manual too.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, those should match. In case of using 32 bit, the program writes each ID or Mask in the corresponding bank.

 else if (CAN_FilterScale == CAN_FilterScale_32Bit)
    {
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR01 = CAN_FilterID1;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR02 = CAN_FilterID2;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR03 = CAN_FilterID3;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR04 = CAN_FilterID4;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR05 = CAN_FilterIDMask1;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR06 = CAN_FilterIDMask2;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR07 = CAN_FilterIDMask3;
      CAN->Page.Filter.FR08 = CAN_FilterIDMask4;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted (edited version) works now.
Turns out I had a problem calculating the addresses by hand.

Thank you @Tagli.